# how to convert JPEG' UIImage to lossless NSData?

Tags: ios, uiimage, jpeg, nsdata

the function of UIImageJPEGRpresentation() can convert JPEG's UIImage to NSData,but is it lossless?
I want to choose an image from system photo album and convert it to NSData,are there some methods can achieve this goal?
Thanks firstly!

Answer (score 0):

For picking image from the device you have to go with `UIImagePickerController`

```
let picker = UIImagePickerController()
```

add following stuff to your `viewDidLoad()`

```
picker.delegate = self
picker.allowsEditing = false
picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary    //You can also go with .camera
```

For open the picker view add this

```
 self.present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Add delegate method for picker view to get picked image

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    let chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
    // Convert image to NSData
    let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) as NSData?   //Your image as NSData
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

***Note**
Don't forgot to add `Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description` to your Info.plist file and `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate`

Answer (score 0):

Though UIImageJPEGRpresentation() takes a quality value as second parameter, it is always lossy!

Use UIImagePNGRepresentation() instead.

Comment: the function of UIImagePNGRepresentation() would change the format of image, I need the NSData which store JPEG image data, because I want to get DCT coefficient from JPEG image in the next step.